# Parse Date from CSV to LocalDate

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, opencsv

How do I parse a date from CSV ("Wednesday, May 5, 2021") into LocalDate in Kotlin? `@CsvDate(value = "E, MMMM d, yyyy")` isn't working for me.

```
@Entity
@Data
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@Table(name="used_vacation")
data class UsedVacation(
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) val id:Long,
    @Column(name="date_start") @CsvDate(value = "E, MMMM d, yyyy") @CsvBindByPosition(position = 1) val dateStart:LocalDate,
    @Column(name="date_end") @CsvDate(value = "E, MMMM d, yyyy") @CsvBindByPosition(position = 2) val dateEnd:LocalDate,
    @ManyToOne @JoinColumn(name="employee_id",nullable=false) @CsvBindByPosition(position = 0) val employee:Employee,
)
{
```

```
private fun createCSVToBeanUsedVacation(fileReader: BufferedReader?): CsvToBean<UsedVacation> =
    CsvToBeanBuilder<UsedVacation>(fileReader)
        .withType(UsedVacation::class.java)
        .withSkipLines(2)
        .withIgnoreLeadingWhiteSpace(true)
        .build()
```

I get this error:

```
Caused by: java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text 'Thursday, October 24, 2019' could not be parsed at index 3
    at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:2052)
    at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1954)
    at com.opencsv.bean.ConverterDate.lambda$determineReadTemporalConversionFunction$9(ConverterDate.java:216)
    at com.opencsv.bean.ConverterDate.convertToRead(ConverterDate.java:306)
    ... 9 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Caused by: java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text 'Thursday,
> October 24, 2019' could not be parsed at index 3

This happens because of the `E, MMMM d, yyyy` date pattern you are currently using: the `E` char for days implies that a short or abbreviated form for days will be used if available so the date parser expects to meet an abbreviated form for *Thursday* like `Thu` and then the error. To parse the *Thursday* day you can instead use the four `E` characters in the `EEEE, MMMM d, yyyy` pattern  because if the number of pattern letters is 4 or more it informs the date parser that the full form for days will be used.

Comment: @NemanjaAndjelkovic Glad to have helped :)